# Android image only push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

[Non-expanded push notification on lock screen (same as notification bar) - OnePlus 7 Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JWOi.jpg)

[Expanded push notification in notification bar - OnePlus 7 Pro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVeqQ.jpg)

What's the API that's used for achieving this? I've been looking around in the firebase documentation as well as browsing the android API and couldn't find an example. Other notifications look how you'd expect them.

Couple of notes:

- I noticed that right when I receive this notification, it has text and body, and after the image loads, the text and body are no longer visible.
- The notification has two images, one for non-expanded view, and another for expanded view. It's not the same image, it's just fading between the two.
- The app is Rest Poker on play store if you wanna give it a try.

I currently use the firebase FCM API, but I understand this might not be possible with it, but maybe by registering the notification on the device might do the trick, as long as we know how to set it up like this.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I am trying to dig into this myself but have found no particular solutions yet.

Comment: It can be done with the android APIs for notification, but you have to set it up in code, and it's also a really bad practice apparently. I am developing for react native so I did not dig this any further sincer I do not have enough native experience, but all the documentation is there. Just use the whole space for a custom layout notification